# Angular.js sends to many posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing single page app with angular. Everything works fine, but
when I first click it send one `$http.post()`
on second click 2 request and so on. so each click +1 request. so if I click 4 times, the fith click will send 5 request right a way. I am wondering how can I prevent increment requests. My code below:

```
app.config(function($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'pages/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    });
});
app.factory('Browser', function($http) {
    return {
        get : function(day) {
            return $http.post('/api/browsers.php', {day:day});
        }
    }
});
app.controller('homeController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, Browser){
    $scope.loading = true;
    Browser.get('today')
        .success(function(res) {
            $scope.loading = false;
            $scope.browsers = res;
        }).error(function(data) {

        });
    $scope.swiped = function(direction) {
        var day = $('.item.active').data('day');
        if((direction == 'next' && day != 'tomorrow') || (direction == 'prev' && day != 'yesterday')){
            $scope.loading = true;
            $('#days-carousel').carousel(direction);
            $('#days-carousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
                var d = $(e.relatedTarget).data('day');
                Browser.get(d)
                    .success(function(res) {
                        $scope.browsers = res;
                        $scope.loading = false;
                    }).error(function(data) {

                    });
                if(d == 'tomorrow'){
                    $('.right.days-carousel-control').addClass('disabled');
                }else{
                    $('.right.days-carousel-control').removeClass('disabled');
                }
                if(d == 'yesterday'){
                    $('.left.days-carousel-control').addClass('disabled');
                }else{
                    $('.left.days-carousel-control').removeClass('disabled');
                }
            }); 
        }
        return false;
    };
});
```

So when index is loaded it send requests to get browserd with default day today.
I ahve bootstrap carousel with yesterday, today, tomorrow.
So when slide is finishing. send new request for other day, but on next slide sends 2 request and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding the  `.on('slid.bs.carousel', function` each time you invoke swiped. You either need to do it another place, so that it is done only once, or you should unbind with `.off` before you bind again.

Comment: Thank you, any idea how I can implement this?

Comment: Moved `.on('slid.bs.carousel', function` our from swipe